# How to mark a parent menu as active if any of it's child is active using Laravel and Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to create a list of menu for my dashboard. It consists of menu name and url. Each item acts like this:

- **Menu 1 <-- this menu is active because it's child (Menu 1.1) is selected**

  - **Menu 1.1 <-- this menu is selected**
  - Menu 1.2

    - Menu 1.2.1
  - Menu 1.3
- Menu 2
- Menu 3

And like this, too:

- **Menu 1 <-- this menu is active because it's child (Menu 1.2) is active**

  - Menu 1.1
  - **Menu 1.2  <-- this menu is active because it's child (Menu 1.2.1) is selected**

    - **Menu 1.2.1 <-- this menu is selected**
  - Menu 1.3
- Menu 2
- Menu 3

I want to achieve this using Laravel 8 and Eloquent.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in a blade file, you can leverage the  `routeIs()` method from the `request()` helper.
The `routeIs()` method can take one or multiple pattern to check so for example, lets say you have 2 routes:

1. `user`
2. `user.role`

so now we are on the `user.role` route and in our blade file we are making the following check

```
 request()->routeIs('user') //false
 request()->routeIs('user.role') //true
 request()->routeIs('user','user.role') //true - since the second is valid
 request()->routeIs('user.*') //true - wildcard is accepted
```

Doc reference to the helper https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#inspecting-the-request-path

I hope it can give you the tool to build your menu and the *Active* state

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the `Route::currentRouteName()` method in conjunction the PHP [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) method to compare the current `route` with your named `routes` in `web.php`.

Given the following `routes` defined in your `web.php` file:

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/colours', 'as' => 'colours'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('colours.index');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/green', 'as' => '.green'], function() {
        Route::get('/', function() {
            return view('colours.green.index');
        });

        Route::get('/apple/', function() {
            return view('colours.green.apple');
        })->name('.apple');

        Route::get('/orchard', function() {
            return view('colours.green.orchard');
        })->name('.orchard');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/red', 'as' => '.red'], function() {
        Route::get('/', function() {
            return view('colours.red.index');
        });

        Route::get('/strawberry', function() {
            return view('colours.red.strawberry');
        })->name('.strawberry');
    });
});
```

Your menu could look something like the following. Note I've not made any sub/nested menu options or fancy methods for generating the menu for the purpose of this example.

**menu.blade.php**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours.green') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours.green') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours - Green</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours.green.apple') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours.green.apple') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours -
            Green - Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours.green.orchard') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours.green.orchard') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours -
            Green - Orchard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours.red') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours.red') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours - Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('colours.red.strawberry') }}"
           class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'colours.red.strawberry') === 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">Colours -
            Red - Strawberry</a></li>
</ul>
```

How this works is that we use `strpos` to inspect the current route name for a match against our named route (`strpos($haystack, $needle)`) and the tenary operator to apply an `active` class if it is found (true), or nothing if it is not found (false).

If you were to navigate to `/colours/red/strawberry`, the `Strawberry`, `Red` and `Colours` links would both have the `active` class applied. If you navigated to `/colours/red` the `Red` and `Colours` links would be active and if you navigated to `/colours`, well you get the idea.